# Flask: Save files downloaded with URL retrieve into the static/img/ folder

Tags: python, flask, urllib

Whenever I try to use `urllib.urlretrieve(href, '/static/img/'+filename)`, I get the error "No such file or directory". However, I do have that directory in there.

If I remove the "/static/img/" the images download fine into the root folder. I need the images to go into the static/img folder to follow Flask convention.

How do I download images using urlretrieve into a directory that I set in Flask?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` at the beginning of your path to make it relative instead of absolute.